# how to render html content in vue multiselect options list in Vue Js

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I want to render that HTML content into options list so need help in resolving this issue.

**HTML**

```
<Multiselect
                    v-model="radiologyTests"
                    mode="tags"
                    placeholder="Choose your stack"
                    :close-on-select="false"
                    :filter-results="true"
                    :min-chars="1"
                    :resolve-on-load="false"
                    :delay="0"
                    :searchable="true"
                    :options="async function(query) {
                        return await fetchLanguages(query) // check JS block for implementation
                   }">
</Multiselect>
```

**Method**

```
async fetchLanguages(query){
         var resData = [];
        await axios.post(this.route("searchRadiologyTests"),{search:query}).then(function(response){
              for( var i in response.data){
                resData.push(response.data[i]);
            }
         });
        console.log(resData);
        return resData.map((item) => {
         item.test_name.replace(new RegExp(query, "gi"), (match) => `<span style='color:red'>${match}</span>`)
        return { value: item.id, label:item.test_name }
        })
    },
```

Any help will be highly appreciable. Thanks

Comment: can you elaborate on what is not working for you?

Comment: Only normal data is rendering but I want to render html content.  Thank you

Comment: Which `Multiselect` library are you using? The `async fetchLanguage` should not have a `function` keyword in the middle?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@vueform/multiselect  
 this multi select i am using